# Python functools.lru_cache has 0 hits

Tags: python, functools

I'm working with a piece of code that looks similar to this (it's actually a lot more complicated but the code below captures the essence):

```py
...
from functools import lru_cache
...
@lru_cache()
def toMemoize(flg, key, sig):
    with open("/path/to/log" , "a") as f:
        f.write(str(hash(flg)) + " " + str(hash(key)) + " " + str(hash(sig)) + "\n")
    ...
...
print(toMemoize.cache_info())
```

The output of the final print statement is:

```
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=13, maxsize=128, currsize=13)
```

This informs methat the function was called 13 times but the cached vale was never used (`hits=0`). Inspecting `/path/to/log`:

```
2553775797797093876 364576801895165551 8302682858752407938
-4582445906785148513 364576801895165551 8302682858752407938
-4582445906785148513 364576801895165551 8302682858752407938
-4582445906785148513 364576801895165551 8302682858752407938
4000922257120027290 1417233507693056889 6473669797807631889
...
```

where each line contains the hash of arguments to `toMemoize`, it looks like this function was called multiple times with the same arguments. Why then is `hits=0`? Any clues, advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these calls all from the same interpreter execution, or multiple? If multiple, then that is the problem. Also, you should provide a standalone executable [mcve]. The current code is not executable on its own

Comment: @DeepSpace Hi. Thanks for the comment. The function in question is part of a large code base and unfortunately I could not reproduce the problem using simplified examples. Does the fact that `misses=13` and that there are 13 lines in `/path/to/log` indicate that all calls to `toMemoize` were made from the same interpreter?